# PlotStyle options not working

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list of LogLogListPlots, lets name it 'Collection'. 'Collection' has *i* elements. When representing them all in just one plot I use:

```
CollectionAllPlots =  
 ListLogLogPlot[Collection,
   PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[x], Opacity[y]}]
```

But the PlotStyle options are not working okay. For those above 'CollectionAllPlots' looks like:

[image]

With not all plots in red nor with the proper thickness nor opacity. What commands should I use?

Comment: What is the structure of `Collection`?

Comment: Just a list of LisLogLog Plots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
funcs = {z^3, z^3 + 5 z, z^3 - 5 z} /. z -> Range[20];

x = 2; y = 0.5;
```

You can either include all of the functions in a single [`ListLogLogPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogLogPlot.html)

```
ListLogLogPlot[funcs,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[x], Opacity[y]]]
```

[image]

Or use [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to combine separate plots

```
plts = ListLogLogPlot[#,
     Joined -> True,
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[x], Opacity[y]]] & /@ 
   funcs;

Show[plts]

(* < same plot > *)
```

Note that a list of styles are individually applied to different functions (cycled if necessary) unless grouped by [`Directive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html) or an additional level of [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html).

```
ListLogLogPlot[funcs,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsoluteThickness[x], Opacity[y]}}]

(* < same plot > *)
```